# what can an editor do with the "none" option for a menu item in the menu editor?

Tags: hippocms

We are exploring the new menu editor that exists now in the channel manager of hippo version 7.9.1. We found the documentation at [1]. But we still have a question. A menu item can have an internal or external link, or have destination "none". We see that a hst:sitemenuitem is created with the property hst:repobased = false. What is the purpose of this destination type?

1. http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/component-development/enable-edit-menu-button-that-opens-menu-editor.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property hst:repobased is 'false' by default.

Menu items of type 'none' won't have a backing link. Such items can be useful in designs where some items are only used to visually group sub-items. For example, a site menu that is rendered as dropdowns (possibly nested) that expand on hover. The top-level items could have no backing page, but only serve as area that trigger the expansion of the sub-menu items.